# Show marker to Google Map on Click

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm using the [Google map react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) package to integrate google map in my react project. I could render the map markers with the lat, long that i have in my json array. But on clicking the map the marker to show the clicked area is not displaying but i'm getting the lat, lng values with _onClick function

```
_onClick = ({x, y, lat, lng, event}) => {
    this.setState({
        lat: lat, lng: lng
    }); 
}
<GoogleMapReact onClick={this._onClick}
    center={this.state.center}
    defaultZoom={this.props.zoom} 
    options = {{ mapTypeId: 'satellite' }}
    style={{height: '680px', width: '560px'}}
>
    {this.state.markers.map((marker, i) =>{
          return(
                 <AnyReactComponent key={i}
                      lat={marker.lat}
                      lng={marker.lng}
                      img_src={marker.img_src}
                  />

                )
    })}      
</GoogleMapReact>
```

How can i solve this to display the marker on the clicked area?

Comment: whenever you are clicking anywhere on map, marker should be displayed there, this is what you want??

Comment: Yes. By default a red marker should be displayed. But its not displaying

Comment: `AnyReactComponent` is rendering the marker?

Comment: Yes, with a custom image marker. But not on click. It shows on loading the map with the given lat, lng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the `lat,lng` for the clicked area, so you need to render the marker for those values. Use one more state variable `isClick`, update that value on click of map, and render the marker conditionally.

Like this:

```
_onClick = ({x, y, lat, lng, event}) => {
    this.setState({
        lat: lat, 
        lng: lng,
        isClicked: true
    }); 
}

<GoogleMapReact onClick={this._onClick}
    center={this.state.center}
    defaultZoom={this.props.zoom} 
    options = {{ mapTypeId: 'satellite' }}
    style={{height: '680px', width: '560px'}}
>
    {this.state.markers.map((marker, i) => {
        return(
            <AnyReactComponent key={i}
                lat={marker.lat}
                lng={marker.lng}
                img_src={marker.img_src}
            />

        )
    })} 
    {this.state.isClicked? 
        <AnyReactComponent key={i}
            lat={this.state.lat}
            lng={this.state.lng}
            img_src={marker.img_src}
        /> 
    :null}   
</GoogleMapReact>
```

Comment: Anyway this is fine and i did like this but, it is not the default marker by google click. But still it is acceptable. Thanks